# I can't find the syntax error in my iverilog {design.sv:1: syntax error I give up.}

Tags: vhdl

library ieee;

use ieee.std_logic_1164.all;

use ieee.numeric_std.all;

entity sqwaveGen is

port (

```
clk : in std_logic;

clk_out : out std_logic;

fall : in unsigned(7 downto 0);

reset : in std_logic;

rise : in unsigned(7 downto 0)
```

);

end entity;

architecture from_verilog of sqwaveGen is

signal count : unsigned(7 downto 0);  -- Declared at design.sv:7

signal count_off : unsigned(7 downto 0);  -- Declared at design.sv:7

signal count_on : unsigned(7 downto 0);  -- Declared at design.sv:7

signal pos_or_neg : std_logic;  -- Declared at design.sv:8

begin

clk_out <= pos_or_neg;

process (clk, reset) is

begin

```
if (not reset) = '1' then

  count <= X"00";

  count <= X"00";

  pos_or_neg <= '1';

elsif rising_edge(clk) then

  if (unsigned'("0000000000000000000000000000000") & pos_or_neg) = X"00000001" then

    if Resize(count, 32) = (Resize(count_on, 32) - X"00000001") then

      count <= X"00";

      pos_or_neg <= '0';

    else

      count <= count + X"01";

    end if;

  else

    if (unsigned'("0000000000000000000000000000000") & pos_or_neg) = X"00000000" then

      if Resize(count, 32) = (Resize(count_off, 32) - X"00000001") then

        count <= X"00";

        pos_or_neg <= '1';

      else

        count <= count + X"01";

      end if;

    end if;

  end if;

end if;
```

end process;

process (fall, rise) is

begin

```
count_on <= rise;

count_off <= fall;
```

end process;

end architecture;

Comment: This appears to be valid VHDL code (albeit not formatted for easy reading) translated by Icarus Verilog from Verilog source. The relationship between it and the Icarus Verilog syntax error message in your question title isn't apparent. Have you accidentally added something to the beginning or your unseen here design.sv file? The VHDL code has comments indicating it was translated from design.sv. Add the [tag:iverilog] tag.

Comment: It isn't clear what you're doing when you encounter the error. See [ask]

Comment: Please edit your question to capture all the code in ``.  Currently it is extremely hard to read your question as much of the code you have tried is not in code blocks.  Please also add some more explanation about what this code is doing and why.

Answer (score 0):

You're trying to simulate a [VHDL](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/VHDL) design with [Icarus (iverilog)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Icarus_Verilog) simulator, which is a [Verilog](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Verilog) simulator and does not support VHDL!
Use should use a simulator which supports VHDL, such as [GHDL](https://ghdl.github.io/ghdl/about.html) or [Xilinx Vivado](https://www.xilinx.com/support/download.html). Also save the file with ".vhd" or ".vhdl" extension.